# What if brew fails to download from an address?

Tags: tcp, connection, gnuplot, octave, homebrew

This is my first question in stack overflow.
I ran into problem with octave(plot), and search on the Internet. They say I should install it with x11. But I failed, it seems the reason is that the address is not valid, but I can download it with my browser. How to fix it?

I restarted my computer and try to install gnuplot again.
This time things get different.

```
==> Downloading http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.2.4.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/lua-5.2.4.tar.gz
Error: SHA256 mismatch
Expected: b9e2e4aad6789b3b63a056d442f7b39f0ecfca3ae0f1fc0ae4e9614401b69f4b
Actual: 3cafbf2ded13e38fdb373b89230b615686e186b8a0dd7885b7323ca9da2e08e8
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/lua-5.2.4.tar.gz
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

I removed the file above,and restart my computer.The statement is like that:

```
Last login: Mon Nov  9 22:14:45 on ttys000
BlueCat56:~ Mac$ brew install gnuplot --with-x
==> Installing dependencies for gnuplot: lua, readline
==> Installing gnuplot dependency: lua
==> Downloading http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.2.4.tar.gz

curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
Error: Failed to download resource "lua"
Download failed: http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.2.4.tar.gz
BlueCat56:~ Mac$
```

Comment: Please do not attach errors or code as images. Instead copy and paste the text directly into code blocks. That said, did you run `brew update` before?

Comment: That error isn't an invalid address error. That's a networking error. The connection was closed on you. Does trying again work? Can you manually download that file with your browser?

Comment: I updated but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I can download it with my browser manually.

Comment: Please run `rm /Library/Caches/Homebrew/lua-5.2.4.tar.gz` and try again.

Comment: I deleted. It gets back to the initial error.curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Comment: it is `--with-x11` not `--with-x`

Comment: Are you using a proxy or anything that could interfere with your connection?